# How to isolate subnet behind Ubuntu gateway?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, gateway

I have the following set up:

```
--> router X provided by my ISP - no admin access to it (LAN IP 192.168.5.1)
    --> network N1 with devices and PCs (DHCP clients of X - IPs 192.168.5.x)
    --> ubuntu server Y acting as a gateway (static IP 192.168.5.110)
        --> network N2 of PCs and devices (DHCP clients of Y - 10.0.0.x)
```

Server Y is set up as a gateway for N2 and works OK, however my requirement is that all the devices on network N2 don't have access to devices on network N1 (anything that is plugged in between router X and server Y) - in other words Y is configured in a way that it bridges the connection between X and itself.

Can it be achieved?

Content of /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.0.100 10.0.0.150;

  default-lease-time 3600;
  max-lease-time 3600;

  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
  option routers 10.0.0.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.5.1;

  option domain-name "N2";

}
```

Content of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.5.110
netmask  255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.5.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.5.1
broadcast 192.168.5.255

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask  255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

Thank you for any help with it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to set up iptables rules that seem to do the trick:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eth1 -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 192.168.5.1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD 2 -i eth1 -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 192.168.5.0/24 -j DROP
```